# Pytorch - do matrix multiplications from slices of 2 tensors

Tags: pytorch, tensor, einsum, matmul

If there are 2 tensors of the following sizes.

```
A = [N x L x T]

B = [N x T x K]
```

Then I would like to do a `matrix multiplication` of slices from the 2 tensors. like below.

`matmul_slice = A[0,:,:] @ B[0,:,:] = [L x T] @ [T x K] = [L x K]`

Then I would like to do it `N` times along the `dimension = 0`.
So that I end up with the final matrix with size `[N,L,K]`

I **do not** want to use loop over N since it *slows* down the computation. I have been playing around with `torch.matmul` and `einsum`, but I cannot get the correct answer.

How can I achieve this in a compact way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.bmm` is what your need, although `torch.matmul` should be equivalent in your case. I think you should recheck your computation.

Comment: That is right! torch.bmm. I have used it a longggg time ago once and totally forgot about it. BTW, with matmul, how will it be done? I cannot seem to get the answer. I will check this as answer as soon as I am allowed to do so.

Comment: you can try to compare the result of `torch.bmm` and `torch.matmul`, it will be the same, just that `torch.bmm` might be slightly faster due to `torch.matmul` is more generalized thus it take some time to determine the right operator between tensors.

Answer (score 1):

The [`matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) operator works like this: `(*, i, j) @ (*, j, k) = (*, i, k)`. 
So in your case, no need to transpose `A`, simply `A@B`.

If you prefer, you can use [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) to show the explicit expression:

```
torch.einsum('bij,bjk->bik', A, B)
```

Note: [`torch.bmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html) works the same way as [`matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) but does not broadcast: `A.bmm(B)`.